# \raggedright in glosses and switching back to normal alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, gb4e

I have to typeset long examples. Sometimes they span several lines. I would like to have them `\raggedright`but this should not affect the translation.

[image]

The code for the glossed example taken from `cgloss.sty` looks as follows:

```
\def\gll%                  % Introduces 2-line text-and-gloss.
    {
     \bgroup%\begin{flushleft}
     \ifx\@gsingle1%           conditionally force single spacing (hpk/MC)
     \def\baselinestretch{1}\@selfnt\fi
%        \vskip\baselineskip\def\baselinestretch{1}%
%        \@selfnt\vskip-\baselineskip\fi%
    \bgroup
    \twosent
   }
```

`cgloss.sty` is a hacked version of `cgloss4e.sty`, which is delivered with the `gb4e` package. `cgloss.sty` is supposed to be compatible with `jambox`, hence the `\begin{flushleft}`is commented out. See http://www.let.uu.nl/~alexis.dimitriadis/personal/latex/cgloss.sty

How can I introduce a `\raggedright` there that only affects `\gll` but not the following translation? I seem to need a command that switches off the `\raggedright` mode.

Answer (score 3):

The `\bgroup` you see is actually closed off in `\twosent`; the translation line is outside this scope. This means that you could add a `\raggedright` just above `\twosent`, and it will go out of scope before the translation is read.

```
\bgroup
\raggedright
\twosent
```

You'll also need to add a `\par` above the `\egroup` in `\twosent`, otherwise `\raggedright` will already be out of scope when its paragraph is formatted. Note that this will break `\jambox`, since the paragraph will already be finished when `\jambox` is seen.

```
\repeat
    \par         % <-- Add this
    \egroup % matches \bgroup in \gloss
   \gl@stop}
```

If it's not something you want on a permanent basis you can achieve the same effect without hacking `cgloss.sty`, and still be able to use `\jambox`, if you put the aligned tiers in `\raggedright` mode like this:

```
\ex {\raggedright 
     \gll Ein Treppenwitz der Musikgeschichte ist, das die Kollegen von Rammstein ...\\
          an afterwit of.the music.history is that the colleagues of Rammstein ... \\ 
     \par}
 \trans ``This is the translation''
```

Again, note the `\par` just before the ragged-right environment goes out of scope.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible to have a raggedright version of `\gll`, say `\gllr`? This seems to be the minimally invasive solution.

Comment: Well, the reason there isn't one already (by default or as an option) is because I didn't see a good way to put arbitrary things on the same line, a la `\jambox`. IIRC, you can get ragged-right glosses at the cost of losing `\jambox` by simply using the default gloss macros (`cgloss4e.sty`, i.e., just don't include `cgloss.sty`).

Comment: Unfortunately the `\raggedright` + `\par` solution does not work if I use `\ex[]{ ... }`.

Comment: Please provide a usable example; I don't see why it wouldn't.